# elasticY(true) with rangeChart does not adapt to new range

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I just started with dc.js based on this [example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/zoom/restrict-panning.html) which I adjusted it with my data.

I want the y-axis to adjust according to the selection of the preview range-chart. In order to do that I added `elasticY(true)` to the main chart. 
If I do this in the example, it works as expected ([see codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JeVQJa)), however, if I use my adjusted code ([see codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YRMoQM)) the y-axis does not adjust at all.

```
var chart = dc.lineChart("#chart")
var rangeChart = dc.lineChart("#range-chart")
var domain = [data[0].date, data.slice(-1)[0].date]
var dimension = crossfilter(data).dimension(function(d) {
   return d.date;
})
var group = dimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
   return d.value;
});

rangeChart
  .height(80)
  .dimension(dimension)
  .group(group)
  .x(d3.scaleTime().domain(domain))
  .xUnits(d3.timeDay)
  .render();

chart
  .height(220)
  .dimension(dimension)
  .group(group)
  .rangeChart(rangeChart)
  .x(d3.scaleTime().domain(domain))
  .xUnits(d3.timeDay)
  .brushOn(false)
  .mouseZoomable(true)
  .zoomScale([1, 100])
  .zoomOutRestrict(true)
  .renderVerticalGridLines(true)
  .elasticY(true)
  .transitionDuration(100)
  .render();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you zoom in on the far left of the chart, you can see that it is automatically adjusting the top of the Y domain, just not the bottom.

The problem is described in the GitHub issue [Stack mixin charts' y-domain is always [0, n] when elasticY(true)](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/667).

It's kind of debatable which is the best behavior here, because standard advice is to show 0 in your charts so as not to exaggerate. They are both valid, so if we changed it we'd have to still offer the `[0,n]` behavior as an option.

The issue offers a workaround:

```
function nonzero_min(chart) {
  dc.override(chart, 'yAxisMin', function () {
    var min = d3.min(chart.data(), function (layer) {
      return d3.min(layer.values, function (p) {
        return p.y + p.y0;
      });
    });
    return dc.utils.subtract(min, chart.yAxisPadding());
  });
  return chart;
}
nonzero_min(chart);
```

Applying it to your chart, indeed a lot more detail is shown, so it's a good choice here:

[image: zoomed min and max]

[Fork of your pen](https://codepen.io/gordonwoodhull/pen/mQYBqL).

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon. I worked. I must have overseen the github issue. Sorry for that. One additional question perhaps: rendering will be really slow (takes a couple of seconds) if I increase my data (I have about 50000 entries to display). I can aggregate off course my data to reduce DOM elements, but when I zoom in, I want to see more and more the details? Perhaps you have a tip for that too? [fork of your fork](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WYBmGb)

Comment: This comes up a lot and I don't think there has been a canonical answer. Could you ask a separate question, please? I've worked up an example to add to the repo but I'd like some space to explain it.